# Regex for splitting below data

Tags: regex, posix

I have a data one on each line in a file as below

```
BMT.PQ
DMZ.IV
VLD.Q
WPS.T
```

I am looking for a regex to split out into two categories of output

One where starting letter of the data is between `A` to `M`

and other

where starting letter of the data is from `N` to `Z`

I tried this

`[A-M].*` for getting first half of data with first beginning letter from `A` to `M`

and i was expecting a result/regex text match of

only :

```
BMT.PQ 
DMZ.PQ
```

but it also gave a match for

`LD.Q` which was incorrect for me.

I even unsuccessfully tried `[(A-M)(A-M)(A-M)].*`

Basically i want to split based on starting letter in the data. One half for data beginning with letters from `A` to `M` and second half for data beginning with letter `N` to `Z`.

Comment: A to M includes D & L -> LD.Q would match

Comment: Yes, i know, because my regex is incorrect. And i am trying to get it to not match any of VLD.Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carat symbol represents the start of the string being searched/matched.  The two regexs that you probably need are:

```
^[A-M]

^[N-Z]
```

Comment: Correct.. Although I guess i need ^[A-M].* to get the part including the dot and characters after dot. Otherwise it was just matching the first letter itself and not the whole words of data.

Comment: It depends it your using a regex to provide a match or using it to extract data from your string.  If it's a match you're looking for then the above will work.  If you're looking to capture parts of the data then you need to look into using the the bracket characters '(' and ')'.  The '.' character means "match any character", so if you want to include an actual '.' character in your regex, you will need to escape it using a backslash character i.e. '\.'.  The '*' character means zero or more occurrences of the preceding character.

Comment: Just curious - IF I have to exactly take a compliment/negate a regex match how do i do it. For above case.

Comment: The '^' (carat) symbol has 2 uses, in the above example it's used at the start of the regex and has the "start of string being matched" meaning.  If you use it elsewhere in a regex it usually means a negation.  So to find a line **not** beginning with 'A-M', you would use `^^[A-M]`... confusing huh?  Obviously matching **not** 'A-M' leaves quite a scope of what characters will match... digits, whitespace, symbols, all other chars, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, all you need is to add the `^` for start of string and `$` for end of string.

```
^[A-M].*$
```

and

```
^[N-Z].*$
```

Make sure you enable multiline mode. Multiline mode (usually the `m` flag) allows `^` and `$` to detect start of line and end of line respectively.

Comment: If your regex engine supports it, you could use a negative lookbehind (or negative lookahead, but in this case I choose to use a negative lookbehind). The regex would then be for instance: `^[A-M].*(?<!^(?:DMZ\.PQ|BMT\.PQ))$`. This will only match lines starting with an upper case letter between a and m, and are not "DMZ.PQ" or "BMT.PQ".